# Правильна ли словесная конструкция "прокачает вас как следует"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Является ли верной следующая словесная конструкция на рекламном плакате:

"Огромный информационный ресурс прокачает вас как следует"?

Насколько в принципе верно употреблять в отношении человека, что его что-то "прокачает", когда говорится об улучшении его знаний, способностей и компетенции? Как было бы верно передать ту же самую мысль:  "Информационный ресурс прокачает ваши способности"?

Answer (score 2):

Современные рекламные плакаты изобилуют сленговыми конструкциями.
Одно из правил создания рекламного плаката - ай-стоппер. "Это то, за что потребитель может «зацепиться» в вашей рекламе. Чтобы рекламный плакат запомнился, нужно удивить и поразить аудиторию."[Рекламные плакаты](http://slovodelo.ru/poleznye-materialy/reklamnye-plakaty/index.php)

В данном предложении "прокачать" как раз является крючком, который цепляет, удивляет: как можно меня "прокачать как следует"?

И всё же такие фразы мне не нравятся. Они, на мой взгляд,  засоряют русский язык, если не сказать уродуют. Этот плакат привлёк внимание, вызвал недоумение и... оттолкнул.

Comment: Мне тоже такие фразы не нравятся, даже противны. Но вопрос был о легитимности.

Answer (score 0):

**Огромный информационный ресурс прокачает вас как следует**

Во-первых, информационный — со строчной буквы.
Во-вторых, слово *прокачать* в современном сленге имеет значение "улучшить характеристики, навыки" и может употребляться по отношению к человеку. Вот, например, название книги, написанной известным блогером и колумнистом, кандидатом экономических наук, руководителем образовательных проектов и преподавателем Андреем Шапенко: «Комиксы про мироустройство. Как понять этот мир, **прокачать себя** и добиться всего, чего захочешь». (https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136271256/)

Comment: а известно ли происхождение данного сленгового выражения? это ведь явно неудачная калька с чужого языка

Comment: Ирина, у меня нет ответа. Советую оформить как отдельный вопрос и ждать, кто ответит.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую